# Flot Charts with xasis Time

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I am trying a flot charts with data

[[1645570986, 0.4624863055203449], [1645570987, 0.4624863055203449], [1645570988, 0.468952235505014],…]
therefore [timespamp, value], however, the time does not appear in the x axis.
Anyone can give me some advice.

```
function CF_real_CPU(){

'use strict';
var cpu = $.plot('#flotRealtime1', [real[0].data], {
    colors: ['#ff5e5e'],
    series: {
        lines: {
            show: true,
            lineWidth: 1
        },
        shadowSize: 0 // Drawing is faster without shadows
    },
    grid: {
        borderColor: 'transparent',
        borderWidth: 1,
        labelMargin: 5
    },
    xaxis: {
        mode: "time",
    tickSize: [10, "second"],
    tickLength: 10,
    axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
    axisLabelPadding: 10,
        color: "transparent",
        font: {
            size: 10,
            color: "#fff"
        }
    },
    yaxis: {
        color: 'transparent',
        font: {
            size: 10,
            color: '#fff'
        }
    }
});
```

}

[image charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvdxP.png)

Thank you
alby696

Answer (score 0):

Your timestamp are in seconds. When using Flot (and JavaScript in general) they need to be in milliseconds. `1645570987` needs to be `1645570987000` and so on.

With the timestamps as they are now, all your data spans less than one second, so the time on the axis is outside the vissible area.